# How to use translate helper in controllers in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

Is there any possible way to translate strings in controllers instead of view?

Right now, in my controllers, if I pass strings like :

```
public function indexAction() {
    return array('message' => 'example message');
}
```

It will be translated in index.phtml

```
<?php print $this->translate($message);?>
```

It works well, but poeditor unable to find strings from controller files

Guess it would be cool if I can use something like :

```
public function indexAction() {
    return array('message' => $view->translate('example message'));
}
```

in controllers

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Also I would like to translate strings passed as form/element attributes (**title**, **alt**) etc. 'Auto translation' is only enabled on form element **label** in zf2 :( So I have to translate these strings within the form class. Right now I'm passing translator helper in form construct, guess is not a good way...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To use view helper in controller, you can use 'getServiceLocator'

```
$helper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('helperName');
```

Either you can use php getText function ___('my custom message') and add "_" as sources keyword in poedit (in catalog properties) so poedit will filter strings from controller. eg:

```
array('message' => _('my custom message'));
```

And as per your code, you can use helper directly like this

```
$translate = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('translate');

array('message' => $translate('my custom message'));
```

Comment: Both methods are working...  :) Which method should be preferred?

Comment: I prefer gettext method since need less effort :)

Answer (score 4):

You should not use the view's plugin manager to get to the translator helper. Grab the translator like [I have explained here already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261115/zf2-use-translator-in-controller).

A copy/paste of that post:

Translation is done via a `Translator`. The translator is an object and injected for example in a view helper, so if you call that view helper, it uses the translator to translate your strings. For this answer I assume you have configured the translator [just the same as the skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L55-L69).

The best way is to use the factory to inject this as a dependency into your controller. The controller config:

```
'controllers' => array(
  'factories' => array(
    'my-controller' => function($sm) {
      $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
      $controller = new MyModule\Controller\FooController($translator);
    }
  )
)
```

And the controller itself:

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
  protected $translator;

  public function __construct(Translator $translator)
  {
    $this->translator = $translator;
  }
}
```

An alternative is to pull the translator from the service manager in your action, but this is less flexible, less testable and harder to maintain:

```
public function fooAction()
{
  $translator = $this->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
}
```

In both cases you can use `$translator->translate('foo bar baz')` to translate your strings.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you please mention where to use first block of code (in which file/function, more specific please)? In my module.php file, in  function 'getServiceConfig()', it's just returning array('factories'=> ***)

Comment: @Sanju it is the configuration of controllers. You can put that in the module.config.php or an alternative is you **skip** the `controllers` key and you start with the `factories` and put that directly in the `getControllerConfig()` method in your `MyModule\Module` class.

Comment: Not working?  Argument 1 passed to MyModule\Controller\MyController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, none given,

Comment: @oskar see my other comment. Please start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I use for that purpose a simple plugin. Then in controller you can do $this->translate('example message');

```
class Translate extends AbstractPlugin {

    private $translator;

    public function __construct(PluginManager $pm) {
        $this->translator = $pm->getServiceLocator()->get('Translator');        
    }

    public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = 'default', $locale = null) {
        return $this->translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
    }

}
```