# ZF2 use translator in controller

Tags: controller, translation, zend-framework2

For a url redirection I need to translate something in the controller.

How can I acces $this->translate(); in the controller?

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Translation is done via a `Translator`. The translator is an object and injected for example in a view helper, so if you call that view helper, it uses the translator to translate your strings. For this answer I assume you have configured the translator [just the same as the skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L55-L69).

The best way is to use the factory to inject this as a dependency into your controller. The controller config:

```
'controllers' => array(
  'factories' => array(
    'my-controller' => function($sm) {
      $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
      $controller = new MyModule\Controller\FooController($translator);
    }
  )
)
```

And the controller itself:

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
  protected $translator;

  public function __construct(Translator $translator)
  {
    $this->translator = $translator;
  }
}
```

An alternative is to pull the translator from the service manager in your action, but this is less flexible, less testable and harder to maintain:

```
public function fooAction()
{
  $translator = $this->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
}
```

In both cases you can use `$translator->translate('foo bar baz')` to translate your strings.

Comment: The newest version of ZF2 changed the key of translator to `MVCTranslator`.

Comment: Doesn't work to me. I've got the following error:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\CorrespondenciasController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, none given, called in /home/inhotim/Trabalho/0-OPE/scape/ProduÃ§Ã£o/Web/scape/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 207 and defined in /home/inhotim/Trabalho/0-OPE/scape/ProduÃ§Ã£o/Web/scape/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/CorrespondenciasController.php on line 141

Comment: @GustavoGonçalves it means your factory is not working. Check the first code block in my answer.

Comment: @JurianSluiman if you mean this code block, yeah, i've double check:
'controllers' => array(
  'factories' => array(
    'my-controller' => function($sm) {
      $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
      $controller = new MyModule\Controller\FooController($translator);
    }
  )
)

this is mine:

'factories' => array(
        'CorrespondenciasController' => function($sm) 
        {
          $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
          $controller = new Application\Controller\CorrespondenciasController($translator);
        }
      )

Comment: @GustavoGonçalves you're using the old routing syntax with `__NAMESPACE__` etc (tip: don't!) and you have `Application\Controller\Correspondencias` as invokable besides `CorrespondenciasController` as factory. Tip: include the FQCN (so, with the namespace) as controller name, remove the `__NAMESPACE__` key and use `Application\Controller\Correspondencias` as factory name, remove the invokable entry

Comment: @JurianSluiman i've updated my pastebin file, i'm getting another error on CorrespondenciasController (Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\CorrespondenciasController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, instance of Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator given, module.config.php on line 144 and defined in CorrespondenciasController.php on line 173) and in IndexController (While attempting to create applicationcontrollerindex(alias: Application\Controller\Index) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type), both stopped working.

Comment: Note: Strangely, i can't use FQCN when calling the Controller, it has to be Controller\<File>Controller.php

Comment: @JurianSluiman I've wondering if this Module.php config could cause any conflict:
http://pastebin.com/8vDnYz4J

Comment: @JurianSluiman resolved. But i had to change some things. Like for example, in the Correspondencias factory:
'factories' => array(
        'Correspondencias' => function($sm) 
        {
          $translator = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
          return new Controller\CorrespondenciasController($translator);
      }

I'll update my Module.config.php. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GustavoGonçalves don't hijack a SO with new questions in a comment. Start asking your own question in a separate thread.

Comment: @oskar please start a new question if you need help

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the translator in controller like in view, just like that:

```
$this->translate('Hello')
```

instead of **ugly**:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('Hello')
```

you can also write the translate plugin for controller, just like view helper `Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate`.

Of course, you can invoke the plugin with the same signature:

```
__invoke($message, $textDomain = null, $locale = null)
```

Just register:

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translate' => 'Application\Controller\Plugin\Translate',
    ),
),
```

And write plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class Translate implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceLocator = $serviceLocator->getController()->getServiceLocator();
        $serviceFactory = new TranslatorServiceFactory();
        $translator = $serviceFactory->createService($serviceLocator);

        return new TranslatorProxy($translator);
    }
}

final class TranslatorProxy extends AbstractPlugin
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = 'default', $locale = null)
    {
        return $this->translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->translator, $method], $args);
    }

    public static function __callstatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->translator, $method], $args);
    }
}
```

**How it works?**
You see, the `ServiceLocator` passed in

```
createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
```

factory in configuration space `controller_plugins`, does have no access to the `Config` service in `ServiceLocator` in controller. So you cannot get the configuration and create the `Translate` object via `TranslatorServiceFactory`.

Instead of that, you can access to the `ServiceLocator` assigned to the controller for which our helper has been invoked, by typing `$serviceLocator->getController()`.

Of course, `$serviceLocator` passed in `createService` method is instance of `Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager`.

**Why proxy?**
The object returned via plugin factory has to implement

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\PluginInterface
```

which is abstractly implemented in

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin
```

so we created proxy object to forward all calls from our plugin to the `Translate` object.

Hope it helped!

I have published an article in my own blog.

Comment: This looks perfect and works centralized as well. Thanks @Athlan!

Comment: Your solution looks nice! Thanks! And you are from Poland :)

Comment: Does not work for me?What's missing? 1- I register the plugin in model.config.php under Application module. 2- I create translater.class in Application\Controller\Plugin. 4- I call the $this->translate('Hello',,__NAMESPACE__,$mylocale) in an other controller.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a nicest way to do it :

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->translate('__your_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$translator = $this->getServiceManager()->get('MVCTranslator');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case works perfectly this solution:

```
namespace MyNS;
class MyCtrlr
{
    protected $translator;

    public function getTranslator()
    {
        if (!$this->translator)
        {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->translator = $sm->get('translator');
        }
        return $this->translator;
    }

    public function myAction()
    {
        $sTrHello = $this->getTranslator()->translate('Hello');
        /*
         * More code here
         */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An *invokable* is a class that can be constructed without any arguments. Since our *MyModule\Controller\FooController* now has a required argument, we need to change this. A *factory* is a class that creates instances of another class. We’ll now create one for our *FooController*. Let’s modify our module.config.php file like this:

```
return array(
     'view_manager' => array( /** ViewManager Config */ ),
     'controllers'  => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             //'MyModule\Controller\Foo' => 'MyModule\Controller\FooController'
         ),
         'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\Foo' => 'MyModule\Factory\FooControllerFactory',
        )
     ),
     'router' => array( /** Router Config */ )
 );
```

Let’s implement our factory class, for this create a new folder in *\module\MyModule\src\MyModule\Factory* and new file called *FooControllerFactory.php*:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyModule\Controller\FooController;

class FooControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {}

    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return mixed
     */    
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $translator         = $realServiceLocator->get('translator');

        return new FooController($translator);
    }
}
```

Let’s now use the *$translator* within our *FooController*. For this we will need to overwrite the default *__contruct()*:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;

class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function FooAction()
    {
      ...
      $msg = $this->translator->translate('Blah blah blah');
      ...
    }
}
```

In my case works fine!!!

Answer (score -1):

You may do it this way:

```
$translate = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('translate');
```